# pandas: csv file, why there is Missing Value after concatenate?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, export-to-csv

Hi anyone who see my question, thx in advance.

I have 3 csv file each of them `don't have Missing values` in column "*financial_tag*", but it has after `contat`.**

the code is here:

```
import pandas as pd

dt1 = pd.read_csv('f:\Sep.csv', encoding='gbk', low_memory=False)
dt2 = pd.read_csv('f:\Aug.csv', encoding='gbk', low_memory=False)
dt3 = pd.read_csv('f:\Jul.csv', encoding='gbk', low_memory=False)

a = dt1.loc[(dt1['financial_tag'] != 157)
        & (dt1['financial_tag'] != 171)
        & (dt1['financial_tag'] != 172)]
b = dt2.loc[(dt2['financial_tag'] != 157)
        & (dt2['financial_tag'] != 171)
        & (dt2['financial_tag'] != 172)]
c = dt3.loc[(dt3['financial_tag'] != 157)
        & (dt3['financial_tag'] != 171)
        & (dt3['financial_tag'] != 172)]

a.to_csv('f:\hahSep.csv', encoding='gbk')
b.to_csv('f:\hahAug.csv', encoding='gbk')
c.to_csv('f:\hahJul.csv', encoding='gbk')

abc = pd.concat([a, b, c])
abc.to_csv('f:\hah.csv', encoding='gbk')

print('done')
```

`hah.csv`:

> financial_tag
>    N    Valid   971810
>         Missing 9

`hahAug.csv`

> financial_tag
>    N    Valid   364144
>         Missing 0

`hahJul.csv`

> financial_tag
>    N    Valid   356924
>         Missing 0

`hahSep.csv`

> financial_tag
>    N    Valid   250751
>         Missing 0

Comment: "I have 2 questions": please create two questions for that.

Comment: Have a look at the a part of your old and new CSV file: Pandas will have added an index. You can use `index=False` in `to_csv` to avoid that.

Comment: @9769953: Thx. Now i understand why the file is getting bigger. But how about `Missing` value in `Q2)`?, `index=False` seems don't work

Comment: See my first comment

Comment: index=False doesn't work for the first or the second case?

Comment: `index=Fals` works for the `Q1)`. However, not for `Q2)`, still got `Missing value` in column `financial_tag`. so...

Comment: Of course it doesn't work for the second question: it's a different question; you can't apply the answer to another question to that. Again, see my first comment.

Comment: Now there is only one question. Please have a look and hope you can offer a answer, still thanks for your comments, It's me missinterpreted `please crease two questions for that` as `two questions under one  "question titles"` instead of `two questions under two "question titles/places"`.

Comment: Are there any other columns? Are the missing values/NaNs in the financial_tag column, or in another column?

Comment: :) Thanks to you and SPSS, I solved the problem by removing `comma` in column `client_name`, what a suprise~  BUT come across another one problem :(  Surprise again~~   ( Width of all data in 2 columns is `1` after `concat` , i'd better post the question in another question if i can not solve it).